# How to set multiple states when calling API request?

Tags: reactjs

I converted my class component to functional. I want to update states of my values when I make a post request to API but my stockId is always 0 and I get `Error: Request failed with status code 500`.

```
function NowyZakup () {

  const [date, setDate] = useState('');
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState(0);
  const [stockId, setStockId] = useState(0);

...

  const saveStock = () => {
    var data = {
      stockId: stockId,
      productId: productId,
      date: date,
      count: count,
    };
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/stock/', data, {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        setStockId(response.data.stockId);
        setProductId(response.data.productId);
        setDate(response.data.date);
        setCount(response.data.count);
        console.log(response.data)   
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
      console.log(data)
  }
```

Comment: Error 500 means that the error exists on the server-side, not on the front end side.

Comment: How/when/where is `saveStock` called? If the request does not succeed the state will never update. So it looks like the issue is with the initial values you use in the request. What do you expect the API endpoint to do with `stockId` and `productId` `0`?